# Searching for a word in a string

Tags: java

I want to find the positions of a particular word in an input string using java. I do not want to use regular expressions.For example if my input string is  " Rama Raman Rama" and if I want to find Rama then it should give me Index number 0 and 11 as output. My code finds Rama in all the three words which I do not want. Some help?

Comment: Did you look at [String API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)? What have you tried?

Comment: Post the code that you have done so far.

Comment: This might help you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html you just need to define the delimiters. perhaps postprocess list of tokens.

Comment: ...but regular expressions are exactly what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Here is your solution :

```
int index=0,j=0;
String name="RAMA RAMAN RAMA";
String[] names = name.split(" ");
for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    if(names[i].equals("RAMA")){
        if(i!=0){
            while(j<i){
                index += names[j++].length();               
                }
            }
            index += i;
            System.out.println("Your match is at : "+index);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: +1; qualified with the fact that OP doesn't want to use regular expressions for some reason; would be -1 if the converse were true. (A regular expression solution would be standard and produce code that's clearer and easier to maintain).

Comment: @Bathsheba yeah, I avoid some inbuilt functionality so that Atul can understand the code easily. Because I think he is a beginner in java.

Comment: Thanks a lot.And yes I am a beginner in java.:)

Comment: @Atul If you got the solution then close the question by accepting the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String name = "RAMA RAMA RAMA";
int position = name.indexOf("RAMA");
```

//This gives you the first position for "RAMA". If you want to have each index for each occurrence use this one:

```
int start = 0;
int end = 0;
while((start = name.indexOf("RAMA", end) != -1){
int position = start;
end = start;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    String str="Rama Raman Rama";
    String[] arr=str.split(" "); // split and grab word to array
    int length=0;
    for(String i:arr){
       if("Rama".equals(i)){
           System.out.println("Index: "+length);
       }
        length=length+i.length()+1;// keep length count here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the classes `Pattern` and `Matcher`. An example when you try to find the word "alpha":

```
String s = "alpha beta alpha anything";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("alpha");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.start());
```

It prints: 0, 11

Answer (score 0):

Simply use indexOf() method. This method will let you know if word is in the text by returning index of word otherwise will return -1 means word is not found.

**String str = "World is beautiful";**

str.indexOf("beautiful"); // This will return value 9 as beautiful word starts at index 9

similarly

**str.indexOf("beautifully"); // It will return -1 as this word doesn't exist in the text**